# cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated not working ionic 5

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic5, cordova-plugin-fcm

I installed cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated by following the ionic documentation and made all the necessary firebase configurations.
I imported FCM into app modules.
Then I put the notification code in my app.component.ts

[image]

But when I do ionic cordova run android I have this as information:

[image]

the problem is that it does not display the token, please someone could help me.

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution, I am getting exact same error

Comment: Any solution? still not working

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I solved my problem using onesignal

Answer (score 6):

**for me the solution was:**

1. ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
2. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@7.2.0
3. import { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx';
4. ionic cordova run android

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved it by importing { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic';

[more details here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-tried-calling-fcm-gettoken-but-the-fcm-plugin-is-not-installed-ionic-5/191883)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, Try to import FCM with this:
import { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx';

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Instead of importing FCM from the npm package, import it like this directly from the cordova package:

`import { FCM } from "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Copy your project to a new folder / repo, and re-install
   `npm install`
2. Add the platform
   `ionic cordova platfrom add ios`
3. Clear cache
   `npm cache clean`

Comment: I copy the whole project except the nodes_module folder? Ok i try that see thanks

Answer (score 0):

install the following plugin first

1. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
2. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

now

```
import fcm as import { FCM } from "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx";
```

remove platforms and add them again then build the project again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I followed the below steps and it worked.

1-delete the node_modules folder.
2-run npm i.

my issue was due to incomplete or maybe corrupt installation of the package.